# C program example

Tags: c, for-loop, modulus

```
void main()
{
    int a,b;

    for(a=10; a < 20; a++ ) 
    {   
        printf("value of a: %d", a);
        for(b=2; b<a; b++) 
        {  
            if(a%b==0)
            { 
                printf(" hello \n");
            }
            else
            {
                break;    
            }               
        }
    }
    getch();   
}
```

In the above code, ( i know it's completely nonsensical, but as a beginner, I'm just trying to clear some points) the output is something like this:

```
value of a: 10 hello 
value of a: 11value of a: 12 hello 
 hello 
 hello 
value of a: 13value of a: 14 hello 
value of a: 15value of a: 16 hello 
value of a: 17value of a: 18 hello 
 hello 
value of a: 19
```

so I want to print the word hello whenever `a % b == 0` so when `a == 12` why is it that "hello" is printed thrice?

Secondly, how do I add the newline characters(`'\n'`) and edit the code so that I get an output like this:

```
value of a : 10 hello
value of b : 11
value of c : 12 hello
value of d : 13
...
```

so on...

Comment: Single step through the program and watch the variables.

Comment: I don't get what you trying to do

Comment: Is it printed twice beacuse  12%2 ==0 , 12%4==0 12%3==0 and 12%6==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specs you provide, something like this would suffice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b = 2;

    for (a = 10; a < 20; a++)
    {
        printf("\nvalue of a: %d", a);
        if (a % b == 0) {
            printf(" hello");
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

[**Sample code**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x7ItkYVA1M3BtO5b)

Answer (score 1):

### *when a=12 why is it that "hello" is printed thrice?*

When `a` is `12`, `b` starts at `2`, and the next values for `b` are `3`, `4`, and `5`.

```
12%2 == 0 therefore "Hello"
12%3 == 0 therefore "Hello"
12%4 == 0 therefore "Hello"
12%5 is NOT 0 therefore, break;
```

That is why you see `"hello"` 3 times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Hello is printed 3 times for 12 because 12 is divisible by 2,3, and 4.  Once you check 5 you break out of the loop.  If you only want to print hello for the first factor use this:

```
  if(a%b==0)
  { 
      printf(" hello \n");
      break;
  }
```

You don't need a break in the else case.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() { 
   int a,b; 
   for(a=10; a < 20; a++ ) { 
         printf("value of a: %d", a); 
         for(b=2; b<a; b++) { 
               if(a%b==0) { 
                    printf(" hello \n"); 
                } 
          } 
          printf("\n");
     } 
    return 0;
}
```

12%2==0 , 12%3==0 and 12%4==0  that's why hello is printed twice. Hope you looking for this.